Clarifying Magnification Values in Photography

Question:
What is the range of magnification produced by a camera lens?
Given the options:

(a) more than $-1$
(b) more than $+1$
(c) less than $-1$
(d) less than $+1$

Context:
I’m trying to understand the behavior of magnification produced by camera lenses, particularly how it varies based on the position of the object relative to the lens.
Analysis:

Definitions:

Magnification ($M$) is defined as the ratio of the height of the image ($h’$) to the height of the object ($h$), or as the ratio of the image distance ($v$) to the object distance ($u$):



$$M = \frac{h’}{h} = - \frac{v}{u} \tag{1} $$

A positive magnification indicates an upright image, while a negative magnification indicates an inverted image.


Typical Scenarios:

When an object is placed beyond the focal length of a convex lens (which is typical for most camera lenses), the image formed is real and inverted, resulting in a negative magnification ($M < 0$).
For distant objects, the magnification is usually less than $+1$, indicating that the image is smaller than the object.


Special Cases:

If the object is very close (within the focal length), the image can be virtual and upright, leading to positive magnification values greater than $1$.



Conclusion:
Considering typical photography scenarios where objects are placed at various distances, I believe the most appropriate choice would be (d) less than $+1$, as this encompasses the common use cases of camera lenses.
Confusion About Options:

(a) more than $-1$: This option is technically true for certain cases, but it can be misleading, as it doesn’t accurately represent the general behavior for real images.

(c) less than $-1$: This can occur in specific situations where the image is larger and inverted. However, this is not typical for standard photography, where the magnification is usually less than $-1$ for certain distances.


Request for Clarification:
Could anyone provide insights or corrections if my understanding is flawed? Are there specific cases where the magnification could be less than $-1$ or greater than $+1$ that I might be overlooking?


Have you seen the size of some things people photograph and compared it to the size of the film or digital sensor? The Eiffel Tower (a frequently photographed object) is 330 m high. You wouldn't see much of it on the sensor if you photographed it with M>1. On the other hand if you're taking a photo of a honeybee you might want M > 1 (and you'd need to buy a special "macro" lens in order to achieve that)

Or are you just fussing about the terminology for inverted images? Most photographers don't care since they can easily flip the film over when they get it out of the camera (or read the pixels out of the digital sensor in bottom to top order instead of top to bottom). So when we say "magnification less than 1" we really mean "|M| < 1" and we don't agonize about whether the image is inverted.

If the image produced by a single lens is upright then it is a virtual image. A virtual image does not affect the film in the camera, so it doesn't cause a photo to be taken. Unless I have misunderstood you this means your magnification is always negative.

The answer is apparently less than -1, so yes, the, the magnification is indeed always negative, however, can't it be both options c) and d)?

Are you trying to show that your exam was mis-graded? Is it for a physics class or a photography class?


Are there specific cases where the magnification could be less than -1 or greater than +1 that I might be overlooking?

If you use a "macro" lens, then the image on the sensor (or film) can be bigger than the object photographed. There is a whole genre of photography called "macrophotography" devoted to using such lenses to take photos of subjects like insects, snowflakes, etc.

(Image source: Flickr user Brian Tomlinson CC-BY-2.0)
As you say, camera lenses are typically inverting so we would normally have M < -1 for such images, even though in casual conversation we say "the magnification is greater than 1" and ignore the inversion.
Note that compound lenses are very common in photography, and macrophotography may also involve additional external elements, so we can't strictly assume that the image will always be inverted.

I appreciate the help, but I think the question itself is unclear. It doesn’t specify whether the image is zoomed in, zoomed out, or if it’s inverted. In most cases, we don't fuss about the image being upside down because that can easily be corrected in post-processing.
Is the question trying to ask about magnification for regular photography (where M < 1), or are they focusing on macro lenses and specific cases where M > 1 or M < -1?

Zoomed in or zoomed out doesn't matter. The typical "full frame" sensor is 26 mm high in landscape orientation. If you take a picture of something bigger than 26 mm high, then for an inverted image, -1 < M < 0.

I was really having trouble understanding the point of your question, so I answered the one clear question you asked: "Are there specific cases where the magnification could be less than -1 or greater than +1?"  and the answer to that is "Yes, in macrophotography, magnification is less than -1 or (less commonly) greater than +1".

Thanks for clarifying! So, just to confirm, when the object is larger than the camera sensor (like something bigger than 26 mm in height), and the image is inverted, the magnification lies between -1 and 0 because the image is smaller than the object but flipped. I think I understand it better now – the key point is that the image is smaller and inverted, so we’re looking at -1 < M < 0 in most cases for larger objects.

@randomuser, yes, correct.

Yep, because both cases were possible, I was confused about what is the correct answer, and what I understood from your help is the answer should be a)More than -1, even though in the answer key,its given c) Less than -1

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
